# Block unknown callers at work, but let them through if they try again

Tags: calls, tasker, call-screening

I have Tasker for Android but I don't know enough about it to be able to implement this.

I'd like this to occur when I am connected to a specific wireless network:

If someone phones who isn't in my contact list, reject the call immediately (straight to voicemail).

If they call again within a certain amount of time (say, 30 seconds) allow the call to come through.

Frankly, I can't even get the first one working. I know it's possible. The time thing is a kind of added bonus

Comment: First time I've ever heard of someone greylisting phone calls.  Intriguing.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/how-can-i-distinguish-important-calls

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried browsing the Tasker's [wiki](http://tasker.wikidot.com/profile-index)? There are some good pre-made profiles there you can use.

The easy way to block calls with Tasker is described [here](http://profileify.com/2010/11/28/blockr-block-unwanted-calls-on-your-android-phone/):

> Open Tasker, create a new Profile and name it "Blockr". Select the "State"
>   context menu and the "Incoming Call" context from that menu. Keep this
>   screen open and follow the instructions below to indicate which calls
>   you would like to block on your phone.
>
> **Programming the Blocked Telephone Numbers**
>
> You have the option to enter a single number, multiple telephone
>   numbers, any number that is not listed in your contacts, or any number
>   that is not listed as a favorite in your contacts.  Any combination of
>   the above options can be included in the blocked call list.  Multiple
>   numbers are separated by the `/` symbol which indicates "or" in
>   Tasker’s pattern match.  You can also use the `*` symbol to indicate a
>   match with any number of characters in the telephone number to create
>   area code (or country code) call blocks.  Here are examples of what
>   you need to enter in the Caller field of the Incoming Call context
>   dialog box in order to create each type of call block list:
>
> To block a single caller with the number 123-456-7890 enter:
>
> `1234567890`
>
> To block two telephone numbers, enter the telephone numbers with a `/` symbol between them:
>
> `1234567890/1234567891`
>
> To block three telephone numbers, enter all three telephone numbers with the `/` between them:
>
> `1234567890/1234567890/1234567892`
>
> To block calls from individuals who are using a caller ID blocking feature enter the number zero:
>
> `0`
>
> To block calls from individuals who are not in your contact list, a pre-configured variable that matches all numbers in your contact list
>   is used (`C:ANY`) with the exclamation point.  The `!` indicates "not" and
>   is literally interpreted as all callers that are not the number that
>   you enter.  In this case, all numbers that are not part of your
>   contact list:
>
> `!C:ANY`
>
> To block calls from both callers with caller ID blocked and those who are not listed as your contacts enter:
>
> `0/!C:ANY`
>
> To block a number of a specific caller and individuals with caller ID blocked enter the number, the / separator, and zero:
>
> `1234567890/0`
>
> To block calls from all numbers except for one caller, enter an exclamation point before the number of the caller that you want to
>   allow.
>
> `!1234567890`
>
> To block calls from all callers except those who are in your favorite list, enter:
>
> `!C:FAV`
>
> To block all calls from an area code, use the `*` symbol to indicate that any number of characters can be matched following the first three
>   digits (US area code) that you enter.  In the following example, any
>   telephone number from the 123 area code would be blocked:
>
> `123*`
>
> Block all calls from two area codes.  Simply use the `/` symbol to combine the area code match in example 10.  In the following example,
>   all calls from numbers with area codes 123 or 321 will be blocked:
>
> `123*/321*`
>
> **Attach the Call Blocking Action**
>
> Click `Done` on the "Incoming Call" context window. Select "New Task" from
>   the top of the "Task" selection window that is displayed. Name the task
>   "CallBlock". Click the (+) button at the bottom left hand of the screen
>   to add a new action.  Select the "Phone" action menu.  Select the "Take Call"
>   action from the Phone action menu. Click `Done` Click the (+) button at
>   the bottom left hand of the screen to add a new action. Select the
>   "Phone" action menu.  Select the "End Call" action from the "Phone" action
>   menu.  Click `Done`. Click `Done` again on the "Task Edit" window. Make sure
>   that the green check mark is displayed next to the "Blockr" profile on
>   the "Profile" screen. Click `Apply`.
>
> Tasker will close and "Blockr" will begin
>   to actively watch your incoming calls for those numbers in your call
>   block list.  When an incoming call with one of the matched numbers is
>   detected, the call is disconnected and your ringer is silenced.  You
>   set the actions up to briefly answer and immediately disconnect the
>   call so it is not sent to your voicemail.

You can modify these instructions to add another condition which checks the WiFi network you are connected to.

Comment: Is there a way to do it when your device cannot use the `Take Call` action?

Comment: Thanks for pasting the contents of the post; the source site is no longer operational. :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Tasker. There is a dedicated App that does what you want: [Harass Me](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.rfc1149.harassme)

Comment: This does not block calls. It takes your phone off silent if you get 3 calls from the same number.